# How to create numerous different lambda functions by for_loop in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, lambda

I tried to create different functions by the following code:

```
a = []

for i in range(5):
    a.append(lambda: i)

print(a)
```

and it showed it:

```
[<function <lambda> at 0x008DA100>, <function <lambda> at 0x008DA0B8>, <function <lambda> at 0x008DA148>, <function <lambda> at 0x008DA190>, <function <lambda> at 0x008DA1D8>]
```

I found that all the functions are different, but I found that it couldn't work later. Althought all the functions indicated to different address, but all the functions showed same number: 4;

```
a[0]()
4
a[1]()
4
a[2]()
4
a[3]()
4
a[4]()
4
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps something to do with the `lambda: a` - instead of `lambda: i` in the loop

Comment: Sorry, it's just a typo. It's actually   lambda: i

Comment: oh! yes! It's a great idea. thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your lambdas are all returning 4 is because they all reference the same variable - `i`. And the value of `i` after the loop ends is 4. Since lambdas are executed when they are invoked - all your lambdas evaluate the same expression: `i` & therefore get the same result.

To get around this you need to bind the value of i as the time of lambda creation. To do that you can use a single-argument lambda with a default value:

```
a = []

for i in range(5):
    a.append(lambda x=i: x)

print(a[0]())
```

Which gives:

```
0
```

as expected.